# What advantages does using var have over the explicit type in C#?

Tags: c#, var

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What’s the point of the var keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209199/whats-the-point-of-the-var-keyword)
>   [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)

I understand how `IEnumerable<...>` for a datatype can make the code a little less readable or how nested generics can seem a little daunting. But aside from code readability, are there advantages to using var instead of the explicit type? It seems like by using the explicit type, you'd better convey what the variable is capable of because you know what it is.

If it's a workplace coding standard, I use it for the sake of teamwork. In my own projects however, I prefer to avoid the user of var.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+var

Comment: `var` is the epitome of all evil. I view it with seething hatred outside of anonymous types and query results. Now ask me about `dynamic`. Go ahead.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram don't use it then.

Comment: As soon as we moved to visual studio 2008 the rest of the dev team i work with began using Var for everything they declared.

I hate the keyword, I hate debugging their code, and ultimately their code takes me twice as long to see what the hell they were trying to achieve.  It wouldn't be so bad if they didn't write functions and methods that are over 500 lines long, littered with Var's

var keyword should only be used by developers who write crisp clean code, and test their code before comitting it into the source control!!

Comment: Type inference often *enhances* clarity by removing boilerplate that isn't adding to the readability of the code.

Comment: also a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c

Comment: @Peter: It sounds like "var" isn't the actual source of the problem with that code.

Comment: Its completely a style thing. There is no advantage because the compiler will have the same result either way.

Comment: @kirk, yeah i'm the code Janitor here, a role that is quickly becoming tiring!! (if only i didn't have mortgage payments lol)

@David, youre right the var keyword isnt the root cause, but it doesnt help matters.

I guess another aspect which may be bad is if it is used within a reflection based environment a code refactoring could suddenly mean a change in behaviour that would not be picked up as the var keyword changes its type accordingly.  Ive seen implementations at previous places where auditing was performed by reflective graph walking, and performed by an Audit(object obj) method.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Using `var` does not change the strong typing. The compiler still knows what the type of the variable is.

Comment: @agarwaen oh god I can't believe I said that 4 years ago. Deleted that comment. I've since learned Haskell and wish .NET could infer types (which I recognize is static still) *more*...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The point of var is to allow anonymous types, without it they would not be possible and that is the reason it exists. All other uses I consider to be lazy coding.

Comment: Lazy? It achieves the same function with less key strokes. From the application's point of view it is raw efficiency.

Comment: @Gusdor It could be argued that it's a little bit harder to see the type if it's implicitly defined.  I tend to follow the pattern of: If the type is long and convoluted e.g. Something<SomethingElse<T>> and would be more easily inferred from the variable name alone, use var.  Otherwise I specify the type explicitly.

Comment: Another advantage of var is that you don't need to add a using statement.
For example var cars = GetCars(); There's no need to add "using Namespace.Car" which you'd have to do if you replaced var with Car.

Comment: Laziness = Efficiency overall

“I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.”

― Bill Gates

Answer (score 9):

Using `var` as the iterator variable for a foreach block is more type safe than explicit type names.  For example

```
class Item {
  public string Name; 
}
foreach ( Item x in col ) {
  Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
}
```

This code could compile without warnings and still cause a runtime casting error.  This is because the foreach loop works with both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.  The former returns values typed as `object` and the C# compiler just does the casting to `Item` under the hood for you.  Hence it's unsafe and can lead to runtime errors because an `IEnumerable` can contain objects of any type.

On the other hand the following code will only do one of the following

1. Not compile because `x` is typed to `object` or another type which does not have a Name field / property
2. Compile and be guaranteed to not have a runtime cast error while enumerating.

The type of 'x' will be `object` in the case of `IEnumerable` and `T` in the case of `IEnumerable<T>`.  No casting is done by the compiler.

```
foreach ( var x in col ) {
  Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
}
```

Comment: `object` does not contain field `Name`. Sure that works?

Comment: Problem #1: If `var x` resolves to `object`, you cannot access the `Name` property. You must still cast.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I came to same conclusion be wasn't *positive*

Comment: @xander, @Anthony the point I'm trying to make is that there are only 2 outcomes with the use of `var` 1) compile = no runtime cast issue or 2) will not compile

Comment: Gotcha, your not saying it won't give a runtime error, just the cast is not necessary at compile-time with regards to 1st case...

Comment: It would if his colleciton (which isn't shown) is of type `IEnumerable<Item>`

Comment: @Matthew re-read the answer...

Comment: @xander, If you look at the code blocks there is no assignment for the `col` variable.  So you have no idea what type of variable it is.  It could very well be `List<Item> : IEnumerable<Item>` or `ItemCollection : IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Matthew your still not seeing it? "Vaya con dios..."

Answer (score 7):

I like it, especially in unit tests, because as the code evolves I only have to fix up the right-hand side of the declaration/assignment.  Obviously I also have to update to reflect the changes in usage, but at the point of declaration I only have to make one change.

Comment: This is the number one reason I `var` the heck out of my code.

Answer (score 4):

It produces no meaningful change in the emitted IL. It is merely a code style preference.

I, for one, like it, especially when dealing with types that have long, generic, almost unreadable names such as `Dictionary<string, IQueryable<TValue1, TValue2>>[]`.

Answer (score 3):

The `var` is just a syntactic sugar. It is always known at compile time what type the variable is. There are no other advantages of using the var keyword.

Comment: Well, there are *some* other advantages.  For example, being able to  store off a reference to an instance of an anonymous type and still be able to reference the properties.  (i.e.  the result of a LINQ query using a Select clause to create ad-hoc objects)

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any real differences. Some people suggest using the explicit type because it can make maintaining the code easier. However, people that push for `var` have the stance that "if we use var, we are forced to use good naming conventions".

Of course if you use vars with the intention of having good naming conventions and that breaks down, it's more painful down the road. (IMO)

Comment: In my opinion, good coding conventions are more important when using 'var' than good naming conventions. Anything declared 'var' is in the current method scope. So long as methods are fairly concise (as they should be), it shouldn't be terribly hard to figure out what the variable is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IAwesome { string Whatever { get; } }
public SoCool : IAwesome { public string Whatever { get; } }

public HeyHey
{
    public SoCool GetSoCool() { return new SoCool(); }

    public void Processy()
    {
        var blech = GetSoCool();
        IAwesome ohYeah = GetSoCool();
        // Now blech != ohYeah, so var is blech and ohYeah is IAwesome.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because "blech != ohYeah, so var is blech and ohYeah is IAwesome" made me smile

Answer (score 0):

Besides the readability aspect you mentioned, 'var' also has the benefit of reducing the probability that a trivial code change will break other parts of your code. If you rename a type, for example. Or if you switch to a different type that is mostly compatible with the former type (e.g. changing from Foo[] to IEnumerable) you have much less work to do to get your code back to a compilable state.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract away the mental complexity of the technicalities to focus purely on the problem domain from your model. you have to make sure your variables are named meaningfully tho.