# Why use var instead of the class name?

Tags: c#, variables, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of the var keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209199/whats-the-point-of-the-var-keyword)
>   [What advantages does using var have over the explicit type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425966/what-advantages-does-using-var-have-over-the-explicit-type-in-c)

I always see other people producing code like:

> var smtp = new SmtpClient();

But why use `var` instead of `SmtpClient` in this case? I **ALWAYS** use

> SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

Is `var` more efficient? Why use `var` instead of the actual variable type? Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What advantages does using var have over the explicit type in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425966/what-advantages-does-using-var-have-over-the-explicit-type-in-c) see also [C# 'var' vs specific type performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-sharp-var-vs-specific-type-performance)

Comment: @MattBall Lol and **THAT's** a duplicate too

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Imagine this.

```
Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String> items = new Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String>();
```

`var` is useful for things like that.

```
var items = new Dictionary<Dictionary<String, String>, String>();
```

Much simpler. The point of `var` is the same as `auto` in C++ 11, the compiler knows the type so why must we repeat ourselves so much. I personally use `var` rarely, but only for lengthly declarations. It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I will defintalley start using more often

Answer (score 21):

No, it's not about efficency, it's only about code-writing style.

Considering that it's about a *style*, this rule could not be applied **always**.

Immagine following snipplet:

`var myVar = Some3dPartFunction()` , what is the *type* of `myVar`? 
It's not absolutely clear, and not good, from code-style point of view, to write in this way.

In short, choose appropriate writing in a clever way.

Comment: If you can't tell what function returns from its name, it's a badly named function.

Comment: @MatějZábský: in a perfect world I would agree with you, but coding in the real office I **always** meet bad named functions, variables, not commented code, not tested code..whatever. You can not design a framework to fit needs of the perfect world..

Comment: @Tigran Of course, I also use specific type declaration where var would not be clear enough for some reason, but in general, I prefer var. You got my +1.

Answer (score 5):

No it isn't more efficient. It's the same thing of write explicitly the type. Infact it is good programming write the type of the variable instead of use `var` because it makes the code more readable.

So:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
```

And:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
```

Are the same thing wrote in two different ways.

Answer (score 3):

It's syntactic sugar:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
```

is equal to:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
```

It's a new feature in C# 3.0, called type inference.

Comment: correctly said. It's the same difference only writing style. Prefer first one for clear readability of code.