# How to Eager Load entire SQL table in LINQ?

Tags: .net, sql, linq, eager

Writing my first Linq application, and I'm trying to find the best way to do the following:

I want to load the entire employees table at once to populate the cache (used for form autocomplete).

I can do -

```
var query = from employee in db.Employees select employee;
foreach (Employee e in query)
{
    ...
}
```

But since this is deferred loading, it generates one query per employee.  How can I eager load the entire table?

I've looked into `DataLoadOptions` but that seems to only work for relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = db.Employees.ToList();
```

By the way, this is equivalent to:

```
var query = (from employee in db.Employees select employee).ToList();
```

There's no reason to force yourself to use query operators syntax when lambda syntax makes more sense and is shorter.

*Side note 1*: The type of `query` object will be `List<Employee>`, however, there is no difference it terms of generated IL and performance if we explicitly specified it.

*Side note 2*: It's important to know the query specified in the question **is *not* executed once per employee**. It's executed just once and is fetched one by one from database (similar to a `SqlDataReader` object running a `SELECT * FROM Employees` query). However, `ToList()` loads all rows in a list making further queries going to that object get executed at the application itself, not SQL Server.

Comment: why would you use a "var" when you know exactly what's coming? couldn't you instead use a List of Employee?

Comment: Chris, it's a subjective topic and kind of religious issue which has been covered in other questions. There is absolutely no difference in the emitted IL (and therefore, performance). It's mostly a matter of style.

Comment: vars are still typed in C# 3.0, it's just syntactic sugar

Comment: All depends on the scope of usage and your preferences. This is a fine read on pros/cons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c