# Early return when an Enumerable has more then X elements in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

What is the most performant way in Linq to write:

`return enumerable.Count() > x;`

I'm at least looking for a solution that:

- doesn't involve counting out the whole enumerable.
- preferably standard .NET Linq.
- should work on different providers.

Note that `enumerable.Any()` works really well for more then 0, but I'm looking for a solution that checks for more than `x`.

**Example:**

Think of a *very* large enumerable that is build with `yield return`.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/169699/961113

Comment: Hi Habib, thanks for your answer.  In this particular case (property that is not accessed by another query) it is evaluated. The Any() works really good for bigger then 0. But how to do bigger than `x`?

Comment: what is wrong with `return enumerable.Count() > x;`, I am not sure there is any other way exist to do the same.

Comment: Well Count() enumerates the whole list, while you already know after the `x`th item that you are done.

Comment: `Count()` doesn't necessarily enumerates the whole collection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating/169699#169699

Comment: About about simple `Skip` and `Any`? F.e: `return enumarble.Skip(x).Any();` ?

Comment: Hi Habib, thanks for answering. It doesn't *necessarily* enumerate the whole collection, but it will when I just access the property in plain code (i.e. not within a Linq to SQL)

Comment: @DirkBoer, for a `List`, there won't be any difference in `Count` property and `Count()` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098186/list-count-vs-count-which-one-and-why

Comment: I've added an example to my question to make it more clear Habib.

Comment: Can anyone of the downvoters explain more? **primarily** opinion-based? Just because I like an answer that is standard .NET or works on other Linq providers? I think there are quite some concrete answers below with insightful reasoning.

Comment: This question is not opinion-based.  It has a very specific set of requirements and an accepted answer.  It is actually an interesting LINQ optimization question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in LINQ method that will give the most efficient solution. Basically you would want to check if the `IEnumerable<T>` has a Count property (via `ICollection<T>`) and if not enumerate it.

```
public static class MoreEnumerable
{
    public static bool HasAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        if (source is ICollection<T>)
        {
            return ((ICollection<T>)source).Count > count;
        }
        else if (source is ICollection)
        {
            return ((ICollection)source).Count > count;
        }

        return source.Skip(count).Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use Take or Skip

Comment: @LuisFilipe True the main body could use Take or Skip, but the important point is that performance is much better if you check for `ICollection<T>` first.

Answer (score 3):

What about simple:

```
return enumerable.Skip(x).Any();
```

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: This _will_ enumerate collections that wouldn't have been enumerated by `Count()`.

Comment: Good point. So if you would really make it performant to all cases, this means you would need to do first a custom check if it is i.e. an IList? ... So I guess you go in the direction of writing your own extension method?

Comment: @DirkBoer Techincally you could check for `ICollection` since that's where `Count` is defined, but yes.  Note that [`Enumerable.Count()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#41ef9e39e54d0d0b) does exactly that. :)

Comment: @DirkBoer Yes, the most efficient solution for standard use cases would check for `ICollection<T>` and use that Count property for comparison first since it is typically O(1). See my answer.

Comment: Except that it will still Enumerate all objects in a non-query context, @DStanley :) I have the feeling mike z's answer is going to be the closest.

Comment: @D Stanley yes, but the same in the oppsite way: when using `yield return` `Count()` will enumerate whole sequence, while `Skip(x).Any()` will enumerate only first `x` elements :)

Comment: @DirkBoer even enumerating in memory will be slower than returning a `Count` property that is likely available without the need for actually enumerating.

Comment: @pwas it will not enumerate if the underlying type implements `ICollection` and has a `Count` property that is pre-calculated (like `List<T>` or `Array`).

Comment: @DStanley : like pwas was saying: `yield return`. That does not implement a Count() property :) it would even be possible to encounter infinite enumerables that way.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most performant (and beautiful) way in Linq to write:
>         `return enumerable.Count() > x;`

What's wrong with just:

```
return enumerable.Count() > x;
```

?

If the actual type of `enumerable` also implements `ICollection`, then it will just return `ICollection.Count` which is typically an O(1) opration.  For `IQueryable`, most query providers will turn it into a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` which is about as fast as you can get.

So there are relatively few edge cases that will perform better than `Count`; probably few enough that trying to code for them is counter-productive.

Comment: It's indeed more of a theoretical then a practical problem, but I've added a proper example. I.e. a *very* large `yield return` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
public static bool LazyCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    int i = 0;

    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        i++;
        if(i > count) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The usage would be:

```
return enumerable.LazyCount(x);
```

Note: I'm really bad at *naming* but you should get the idea, you can modify it however you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use LINQ I would use something like

```
enumerable.Take(x).Count() == x
```

Even though I would prefer Selman22 approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if you have more than 5 you can do the following

`enumerable.Take(6).Count() == 6`