# How to return ICollection<object> from linq, when using select new object() {}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the below linq currently working, but what I would really like is to return an `ICollection<SexyPeopleVM>` instead of a list. But I can't get my head around the syntax and other alternative I've tried have failed at runtime.

**Is this possible? How can I achieve this?**

```
var o = from s in sexyPeople
                    select new SexyPeopleVM()
                    {
                        id = s.ID,
                        title = s.Title,
                        views = s.Views,
                        url = s.GetFullyQualifiedURL(),
                        friendlyDate = s.DateCreated.AsShortFriendly()
                    };
            List<SexyPeopleVM> list = o.ToList();
            return list;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`.
You don't need to do anything.

Comment: yes. Just specify `ICollection<SexyPeopleVM>` as your function's return type.

Answer (score 4):

As SLaks said, he beat me posting, but I wanted to add, you can make your code a little cleaner also:

```
return (from s in sexyPeople
                    select new SexyPeopleVM()
                    {
                        id = s.ID,
                        title = s.Title,
                        views = s.Views,
                        url = s.GetFullyQualifiedURL(),
                        friendlyDate = s.DateCreated.AsShortFriendly()
                    }).ToList();
```

One other thing, get [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) if you do not have it.

I now use

```
var list = new List<object>();
```

instead of:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
```

[A good post as to why to use var.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737835/resharper-and-var)

This is just a coding style buy Resharper cleans up your code quite a bit.

I get in the habit and alot of other cleaner habits, like the two above, thanks to Resharper. I can't live without it now.

Comment: Alternatively, `sexyPeople.Select(s => new SexyPeopleVM(){...}).ToList()`

Comment: yeah true, that just seems to confuse people who are newer to C# so I don't use that unless I have to.

Comment: Your code won't compile.  The change that you made to simplify it was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the ICollection specifically, just do

```
 return o.ToList() as ICollection<SexyPeopleVM>;
```