# Is declaring variables as 'var' a good practice?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)

Which declaration should be accepted ?

```
var str = "Hi";
```

OR

```
string str = "Hi";
```

Even, my team lead always asks me to use 'var' when I iterate through collection using foreach, although the collection is typed one!

In C#, we usually declare variables explicitly. But I have a ReShaper installed and it prompts to change declaration from 'string' to 'var'. Is it a good practice? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a subjective/preferential question**, and likely is a duplicate of others that have come before. I wouldn't be happy about ReSharper suggesting that everything should be declared as `var`.

Is it a **good** practice? Suggest that it's not super-relevant or there are bigger fish to fry in terms of good code. I'd suggest developer work or focus more on writing:

- shorter/smaller methods.
- well named variables and methods.
- readable code. If this includes/excludes var

You can't avoid `var` when using anonymous types.

Readability is my chief concern. For declaring simple data types like `string`, `int`, `ulong`, I'd suggest that you're not really doing yourself any favours in terms of keystrokes or readability.