# Does "var" keyword hampers code readability?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-readability

I just started using Resharper. One of its features is that it suggests changes to the code based on, i suppose, good coding practices.

One of the changes it suggested is to change the variable type to var during assignment. I kept on changing and now the code has var everywhere. Somehow I get the feeling that "var" keyword makes the code a bit difficult to understand.

Is it a good coding practice to use "var" whereever possible or is it better to stick with the actual type. (except anonymous types where its required to use "var")

Thanks.

Comment: Oy, I anticipate subjective arguments.

Comment: Highly subjective -- wars have started over questions such as this.

Comment: Would make a good community wiki discussion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)

Comment: You should re-ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ... ok, it's kind of subjective, but there are suggestions in the c# programming guide. IMHO, there is no reason to close this question.

Comment: @Stefan - Yes there is - it's a duplicate of [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)

Comment: @Chris: it had not been closed as duplicate ... but anyway. I could move my answer over there, but it wouldn't be read anyway.

Comment: @Stefan - sometimes we get the right result, but the wrong reason is displayed. It might be that there were 2 votes for duplicate and 3 for subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) suggest using var when it enhances readability, for instance when the type is obvious, too complicated or not important at all.

> The var keyword can also be useful
>   when the specific type of the variable
>   is tedious to type on the keyboard, or
>   is obvious, or does not add to the
>   readability of the code. One example
>   where var is helpful in this manner is
>   with nested generic types such as
>   those used with group operations. In
>   the following query, the type of the
>   query variable is
>   `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Student>>`. As long as you and others
>   who must maintain your code understand
>   this, there is no problem with using
>   implicit typing for convenience and
>   brevity.

There is no general rule. There are situations where the explicit type may enhance readability.

Examples:

```
var x = new Thingy(); //type is obvious

var x = dict.Where(x => x.Value > 3); // type is complex and not important

Foo(GetValue(FromOverThere())); // type is implicit anyway

// equivalent to:
var fromOverThere = FromOverThere();
var value = GetValue(fromOverThere)
Foo(value);

FooDocument doc = repository.Get(id); // glad to see the type here.
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `var` when you have code like this:

```
var surelyAnXText = new XText(...);
```

where you always can tell the want type we are declaring a variable of. But not when you have something like this:

```
var whatIsThis = foo.Some_Method_Where_You_Cant_Tell_The_Return_Type_From_The_Name();
```