# modify a list while doing foreach inside lock()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

atm I do it like this:

```
lock (LockObj)
 {
     foreach (var o in Oo)
     {
        var val = o.DateActive;
        if (val.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now) Oo.Remove(o);
     }
}
```

and I get this error:

***Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute***

how this should be done?

Comment: Use List<T>.RemoveAll or similar. By the way, is there any reason you are giving the items at later indices a slightly lower chance of survival? That does look pretty strange. I would think you want to evaluate DateTime.Now *once*.

Comment: @Ani my web-site's users ping the server (ajax) at a specific interval of time, when they stop pinging they aren't on-line

Comment: @Ani while evaluation `DateTime.Now` only once is certainly cleaner, it doesn't matter here. But `RemoveAll` is certainly preferable over hand coded loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a regular `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Oo.Length; ++i)
{
    var val = Oo[i];
    if (val.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        Oo.RemoveAt(i);
        i--; // since we just removed an element
    }
}
```

The reason you cannot edit a collection with a `foreach` loop is because `foreach` uses a readonly `IEnumerator` of the collection you are iterating.

Comment: But if you Oo.RemoveAt(i), things are going to get very screwy for next i.

Comment: Just decrement i: `Oo.RemoveAt(i--);`

Answer (score 2):

you can't modify a collection you are enumerating..
to change it get a copy of it and change it.

```
for(var k in OO.ToList())
.....
```

or

use count and iterate the collection with index,

```
for (int i=0;i<OO.Count();i++)
.....
```

Comment: `for(var k in OO.ToList())` won't compile, and still has the same problem after fixing that syntax error anyway ;)

Comment: @TheBigO - did u import the namespace System.Linq?

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy - I didn't try to compile it. Does that compile with linq?

Comment: @TheBigO- yep,ToList() is an extension method,which is present in LINQ.

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy - But does LINQ also make `for()` statements behave like `foreach()` statements?

Comment: No,__for__ and __foreach__ have nothing to do with the LINQ

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to the lock.

Use a for() loop instead of foreach().

I can't 100% replace your code because your code provides no hint of what collection type "Oo" is. Neither does the name "Oo". Perhaps one of the evils of `var` keyword overuse? Or maybe I just can't see enough of your code ;)

```
int size = Oo.Length();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (Oo[i].AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now){
        Oo[i].RemoveAt(i);
        size--; // Compensate for new size after removal.
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the use of `var` evil?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I didn't say it was, I said "one of the evils of *var keyword overuse*".

Comment: Sorry. Allow me to rephrase. ;-) How can `var` be overused? What's the evil?

Comment: @Enigmativity - See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot modify the collection if you are iterating with `foreach`. You have two options, Loop with `For` instead of `foreach` or create another `Collection` and modify that.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is completely unrelated to locking.

If you add/remove elements from a `List` all iterators pointing to that list become invalid.

One alternative to using an iterator is manually working with indices. Then you can iterate backwards and remove elements with `RemoveAt`.

```
for(int i=Oo.Count-1;i>=0;i--)
{
  var o=Oo[i];
  if (o.DateActive.AddSeconds(30)<DateTime.Now)
    Oo.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Unfortunately this native implementation is `O(n^2)`. If you write it in a more complex way where you first assign the elements to their new position and then truncate the list it becomes `O(n)`.

Buf if `Oo` is a `List<T>` there is a much better solution. You can use `Oo.RemoveAll(o=>o.DateActive.AddSeconds(30)<DateTime.Now)`. Unfortunately you there is no such extension method on `IList<T>` by default.

I'd write the code like this:

```
lock (LockObj)
 {
     DateTime deleteTime=DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30);
     Oo.RemoveAll(o=>o.DateActive<deleteTime);
}
```

As a sidenote I'd personally use UTC times instead of local times for such code.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<OOItem> oo = new List<OOItem>();

        oo.Add( new OOItem() { DateActive = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-31) });

        lock(LockObj)
        {
              foreach( var item in oo.Where( ooItem => ooItem.DateActive.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now  ).ToArray())
              {
                 oo.Remove(item);
              } 
        }

        Debug.Assert( oo.Count ==  0);
    }
}

public class OOItem
{
    public DateTime DateActive { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest an approach that avoids messing around with decrementing loop indexes and other stuff that makes code difficult to understand.

I think the best bet is to write a nice query and then do a `foreach` over the result of turning the query into an array:

```
var inactives = from o in Oo
                where o.DateActive < DateTime.Now
                select o;

foreach (var o in inactives.ToArray())
{
    Oo.Remove(o);
}
```

This avoids the issue of the collection changing and makes the code quite a bit more readable.

If you're a little more "functionally" oriented then here's another choice:

```
(from o in Oo
 where o.DateActive < DateTime.Now
 select o)
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(o => Oo.Remove(o));
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Parallel.ForEach(oO, val=> { oO.Remove(val); })

Parallel doesn't have the IEnumerator problem !

Comment: would it make any sense to use parallel inside lock()