# Converting binary string back to normal string

Tags: c#, .net

```
string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
    foreach (byte b in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input))
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I found this function online to convert a string into binary. How would I do the reverse?

For example converting the word "hello" to binary using the function given above and then converting the resulting binarystring back into the original word/string?

I'm trying to do this in C# and that my input which I want to convert back is the string given by the function above

Comment: This is pretty much your answer [C#  Byte array to Unicode string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5056351/1734730)

Comment: I already tried this, but somehow it only gives out gibberish. Could it be because of the format provider when converting the byte to string?

Comment: You should rather use bold text `**text**` instead of going for uppercase. Makes it looking bad.

Comment: If you do not have unicode characters don't use unicode encoding.  Instead use Encoding.UTF8.  Strings/characters are two byte objects with a private property that indicates Why use a binary string when you can use a byte array.  Use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string) and then Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[]);

Comment: Thanks for your help. But please note that I'm using a string as input. I(f I convert it to a bytearray and then back to a string it won't help me. I bgasically need to do the reverse of what the function given in my post does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your input function is wrong.
If you pass the string "Hello" the returned string is

```
 "10010001100101110110011011001101111" (35 characters ??? )
```

but this is not a correct representation in binary of the word `Hello` where every character should be represented by a series of 8 0|1 (total 40 characters)

The main reason for this error lies in the `Convert.ToString` that strips away the leading zeros from the byte passed to the conversion.
So the letter `H` should be `01001000` (8 chars) but the conversion returns `1001000` (7 chars) thus everything that follow is wrong and impossible to correctly convert back.

You could fix the input function with

```
string GetBits(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
    {
        string temp = Convert.ToString(b, 2);

        // This ensure that 8 chars represent the 8bits
        temp = "00000000".Substring(temp.Length) + temp; 
        sb.Append(temp);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

While the conversion back to "Hello" could be written as

```
string GetString(string input)
{
    // Probably a checking on the input length as multiple of 8 
    // should be added here....

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (input.Length > 0)
    {
        string block = input.Substring(0, 8);
        input = input.Substring(8);
        int value = 0;
        foreach (int x in block)
        {
            int temp = x - 48;
            value = (value << 1) | temp;
        }
        sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(value));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! What would I have to change when using unicode?
Just `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input)`

Comment: Uhm not only that. Also the conversion back to string requires changes to handle blocks of 16 bytes. But this should be tested and I am sorry but I have no time now