# Why C# Need Integral Types already it has "Var" keyword?

Tags: c#, variables, types, reference, var

That can be silly question but I really don't know the reason.

```
    // i is compiled as an int
    var i = 5;

    // s is compiled as a string
    var s = "Hello";

    // a is compiled as int[]
    var a = new[] { 0, 1, 2 };

    // expr is compiled as IEnumerable<Customer>
    // or perhaps IQueryable<Customer>
    var expr =
        from c in customers
        where c.City == "London"
        select c;

    // anon is compiled as an anonymous type
    var anon = new { Name = "Terry", Age = 34 };

    // list is compiled as List<int>                             
    var list = new List<int>();
```

If so, why `C#` needs integral types like `int`, `string`, `int[]`, `List<>` ? If we can do that only with `var` keywords, why are there integral types?

Another way,

What is the difference between these ?

```
var s = "Hello";
string s = "Hello";
```

Comment: var (as answered many times before) is syntactic sugar; it saves the coder typing characters that's all. At compile time the actual assigned type is used. It is not at all like 'dynamic'

Comment: Are you asking why C# is strongly-typed?

Comment: Well the actual reason would be it all started from 1.0 and not 3.0

Comment: @Alex `var i = 5` and `int i = 5` are equally strongly typed

Comment: Try to write `var i;` and you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in no particular order...

- `var` is only a compiler construct; even `var i = 4;` is typed as `int`
- C# hasn't always had `var`, and you can't remove keywords without utterly breaking existing code.
- you can only use var in ***method variables*** - not fields, parameters, return types etc.
- most people are happy to type `int` in place of var! Especially when the type matters and there are bytes, floats, enums, decimals etc that ***all*** work with the literal `0`; i.e. `short x = 0; int y = 0; long z = 0;` - why change **only** `int` to `var` there?
- you can't use `var` to specify a generic type parameter (`<T>`) or in a `typeof`
- you can't use `var.TryParse` in place of `int.TryParse`

Comment: +1 because I'am one of people who like write types :)

Comment: And you can't use var to specify lambdas. i.e var a = () => {}; won't work (but you can type var a = () => {} as Action ;) )

Comment: `you can only use var in method variables - not fields, parameters, return types etc` is my real answer.

Answer (score 6):

Many people would argue that it is better practice to write `int i = 5` rather than `var i = 5`.  There are many reasons for this, but the most compelling to me is that I can look at the code and know immediately, without stretching my brain, what type `i` is.  This allows my brain to concentrate on the harder problems.

In fact `var` was introduced to declare variables whose types could not easily be named.  It was not introduced as a convenience, although it can be used that way.

Answer (score 4):

The `var` keyword is just syntactic sugar, which can only be used for local variables in methods. It's still a strongly typed variable. You can hover the mouse over it in visual studio to see what type it is.

We still need types as otherwise how would you do `var list = new List<int>();`? You need to type `List<int>` somewhere!

In many cases its best to be explicit, for example when working with literals that could be a number of different types, or to increase readability.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between `var s = "Hello";"` and `string s ="Hello";"`. However, there's a big difference between `var foo = new Foo();` and `IFoo foo = new Foo();`. In the first case all of Foo's members are accessible, in the latter it's ensured that only interface members is used. This may be important to ensure that the behavior is compatible with the interface, not only the concrete implementations.

Also, `var` can't be used to pass function arguments or to declare member variables. As of to use or not to use `var`, I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c).