# Accessing method from another class

Tags: c#

I have a simple button which will open up the `AddStation` form (this button is placed on the `MainForm` form):

```
var AddStation = new AddStation();
AddStation.Show();
```

It shows the form fine, however the form `AddStation` has a save button. When this button is pressed the `AddStation` form is closed, **but** I want to run a method which is in the `MainForm`'s class (to update a listbox which is present on `MainForm`).

This isn't possible the way I do it right now, since the form `AddStation` doesn't have a reference to the `MainForm`, but how will I do this? How can I run the method `MainForm.UpdateListBox` from the `AddStation` form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was Dunsten who deleted his answer, but worked perfectly.

I added

```
public MainForm mainForm;
```

on top of my `AddStation` class, then when calling the form I used this:

```
var AddStation = new AddStation();
AddStation.mainForm = this;
AddStation.Show();
```

and now I'm able to access methods / objects from `AddStation` (which I was after)!

Answer (score 3):

You could subscribe to `FormClosing` on Main:

```
 AddStation.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(AddStation_FormClosing);
```

And then on Main do something like:

```
void AddStation_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  UpdateListBox ();
}
```

This will, of course, fire when the form is closing.

**Edited:**
You could also declare your own event on `AddStation` and have Main subscribe to it:

On AddStation:

```
public event EventHandler TimeToUpdateListBox;
```

And whenever you think it is appropriate (maybe when the button to close AddStation has been clicked):

```
if (TimeToUpdateListBox != null)
  TimeToUpdateListBox(this, new EventArgs());
```

On Main:

```
void AddStation_TimeToUpdateListBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UpdateListBox ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using a var for AddStation instead of the actual class object?

Typically what I do is do something like this:

```
AddStation frmAddStation = new AddStation();
if (frmAddStation.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    //<call your update listbox function here>
}
```

Then in the function called from your Save button on AddStation make sure you do this:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

The benefit of this is that if you have a cancel button on your form, if you set

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
```

Then your code doesn't execute the ListBox update.

Comment: In a method scope, `var` is an implicitly typed variable. Using `var` instead of `AddStation` is simply another way of declaring the type, not a "class object". The "class object" is what is declared on the right hand side of the declaration. The left side is the `type`. [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: Other than less typing, why would you use var versus explicitly declaring type for strongly typed objects? I understand why you use var when constructing LINQ statements but not sure why you would use var here, is this more of a preference thing or is Microsoft pushing devs to use this syntax?

Comment: The use of `var` has been discussed at length. A good discussion: [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41479/9664). IMO, the general rule-of-thumb is to use `var` when the right hand side explicitly declares the type; otherwise, use the type.

Answer (score 0):

Set DialogResult of Save button to `DialogResult.OK`. Then show second form this way:

```
using(var AddStation = new AddStation())
{
   if (AddStation.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      // update listbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the overloaded Show mthod and pass the main form as the owner & then invoke the appropriate method on the Main Form - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx