# What is the benefit of declaring 'var' for an object?

Tags: c#, var

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

1. What is the benefit of using `var` for initializing an object as in the first line of following code, `var sp` is used for SerialPort.
2. What is the benefit of disposing an object after using it? As in following code, the object `SerialPort` is disposed after an [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) has been sent to the recipient.

Code:

```
using (var sp = new SerialPort(cbcomport.Text))
{
    sp.Open();
    sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + dt.Rows[i]["PhoneNo"] + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
    sp.WriteLine(tbsms.Text + (char)26);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders Abel for Editing

Comment: Both of these questions have been asked and answered many times here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) With `var` you don't have to write out the word `SerialPort` twice.

If you're calling a method that returns an object that might have a very complicated signature, using `var` definitely helps. The most common case is for linq queries.

```
var q = from c in orders
        order by c.id
        select c;
```

The type of q is `IOrderedQueryAble<Order>` which I prefer to not write out.

2) Disposing the serial port when you're done with it immediately closes it and releases it for other applications to use it. If you don't dispose it, the port will be locked until the GC has collected the object (which may take quite some time).

Comment: what about the second question???

Comment: @kashif it's answered too. Read again.

Comment: does disposing free the memory it occupied and terminates the object???

Comment: @kashif no, `Dispose` only frees unmanaged resources. And don't shout.

Comment: Thanks Ander Abel now I understood it... Thanks Alot

Comment: @wRAR: `Dispose` does nothing, as it is defined in an interface.  If your class implements IDisposable, and your class holds managed resources (such as a SqlConnection), and you release these during the call to `Dispose`...  Or unhooks event listeners...  then it is freeing managed resources.

Answer (score 4):

1. With `var` you type less.
2. The GC will be free to collect the disposed object when it sees fit. If it is an unmanaged resource, the call to `Dispose` will cleanup those resources.

Comment: what is unmanaged resource. is it something like that an object occupies the space in memory when created and disposing it after using it = closing it to free the memory or somthing else??

Comment: @kashif - The parallel port is one. Other can be: file systems, databases. Basically, any code that is not .NET or that uses resources that are not .NET (COM objects, ports, buses etc...)

Answer (score 1):

In your case var is an option of not writing  SerialPort twice like

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(cbcomport.Text)
```

and

```
var sp = new SerialPort(cbcomport.Text)
```

Both of the above statements are same

moreover in some places like LINQ when we are not sure what the outcome of LINQ query is then we write var to store fetched results.