# How to load left parts of Uris using Linq in c#

Tags: string, linq, uri

I have a list of Url in file url.data like this

```
http://site1.org/info.php
http://site2.com/info/index.php
http://site3.edu/
```

I load in array of string with link function

```
string[] asUrlData = File.ReadAllLines("url.data").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
                                                  .Distinct().
                                                  .ToArray();
```

I want to get the left parts of Uris in the array like

```
http://site1.org/
http://site2.com/info/
http://site3.edu/
```

Is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`URI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class. Use [`IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) to check if it is well formed and `strUri.Substring(0, strUri.LastIndexOf('/') +1` to get the authority + path without file.

```
String[] uris = File.ReadLines(path)
            .Where(u => Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(u, UriKind.Absolute))
            .Select(u => { 
                var p = new Uri(u).ToString();
                return p.Substring(0, p.LastIndexOf('/') +1); 
            })
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();

Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, uris));
```

**Edit**: Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/UckoV

Comment: It's OK. Thank you for your help.

Subsidiary question: is it better to use `var uris` that `string[] uris` ?

Comment: @PapyRef: I've used var here to be able to change the query easily. Normally it's better to tell explicitely what the query returns (for readability). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp Remember to accept answers :)

Comment: I am a new user (and French ;) )
What do you mean by _Remember to accept answers_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Tim Schmelter posted good solution, but i came up with another that uses regex

It might be better, if you wont to easily manipulate of output URL form.

```
string[] urls2 = urls
                .Select(s => Regex.Match(s, @"(http://){0,1}[a-z0-9\-\.]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,5}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToString())
                .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                .ToArray();
```

If regex will be a string taken from config file etc, you can easily change it

DEMO : http://ideone.com/nRR0m

P.S.
@Tim Schmelter: very nice page for those demos, added to favorites ;)