# All Sundays in month, this month has no Sundays yet,issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code, it failed because thisMonthSundays are empty:

```
 public ActionResult TradeUKKPISearchesData() //show dropdownlist in the view
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var lastMonth = now.AddMonths(-1);
    var thisMonthSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(now.Year, now.Month).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
    var lastMonthSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date); //problem here, must add some sort of check here?
    var sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth = 4;
    var sundays = thisMonthSundays.Concat(lastMonthSundays.Skip(Math.Max(0, lastMonthSundays.Count() - sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth)).Take(sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth));

    var allSundaysInThisMonth = new SundaysInMonthViewModel
    {
        AllSundays = sundays.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            Text = x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        })
    };

    var selectedSunday = new SundaysInMonthViewModel
    {
        SelectedSunday = thisMonthSundays.Where(x => x <= now).Last() //failed here
    };

  return View(allSundaysInThisMonth);
}

private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesOfSundays(int year, int month)
{
  var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  for (int i=1; i <= ci.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month); i++)
  {
      var date = new DateTime(year, month, i);
      if ((date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) && (date <= DateTime.Now))
      {
          yield return date; //skips all for this month
      }
  }
}
```

I need to fix this, please help with ideas?
thanks

Comment: You should not use var everywhere. Consider this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: simple question: Did you run this code today? cause given your code, there is no Sunday on October :)

Comment: yes there is no sunday in October yet, and yes I ran it today, so I must add a check to see if sundays in month = 5 and not 4 so I can get yesterday in my list, I read that if you want to count you IEnumerable, the only way is to iterate through it, there is no .count()... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Octobar month do not have SUnday so far, the variable `SelectedSunday` is empty....

You can use `LastOrDefault()` instead :

```
SelectedSunday = thisMonthSundays.Where(x => x <= now).LastOrDefault() ;
```

Note : The Default value for `DateTime` Type is `DateTime.Min` which is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why thisMonthSundays is empty. It just return a default date which might not be the best solution here.

Comment: @Charlie_cat : LastOrDefault() is helpful in empty collection souce which do not throw expception while collection is empty instead it gives default value of that type if the collection is empty.....

Comment: @lcfseth : It simply returns empty as this month(OCtobar) do not contain sunday so far......About LastOrDefault(), it's helpful in empty collection...

Comment: @LolCoder Not saying your answer is wrong :) Just stating that this doesn't explain the exception. Also, the default value for DateTime is DateTime.Min not null. You should add a condition check to your code IMAO.

Comment: thanks all, i understand now..I must still fix my other problem..will see what I can do there.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code here.

1. Using `var` is not something you want to do everywhere.
2. You should never use arbitrary values in your functions. Instead of checking that the days are prior to today, you should add a limit parameter to your function and pass `DateTime.Now` 
   on the call.
3. Your function is already returning all the Sundays of a given month that are prior to today. Your Linq Request is just a replication of code and will return the whole collection   every-time.
4. Since today is 10-01 and that we are Monday, there is no Sundays on October prior to today. This is why your collection is empty.