# What should i use: var or explicitly type specify?

Tags: c#, oop, resharper

I use extension for VS named "ReSharper". It corrects my code and always says that i need to use "var" instead explicitly type specify. Why?

P.S. sorry for my english and check me please=)

Comment: Because it's configured to `always use var`. You always can fix it by configuring R# settings

Comment: It's up to you. Choose whatever you're comfortable with. This question is subjective and not suited for SO.

Comment: From Eric Lippert: [Uses and misuses of implicit typing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx). Also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881801/when-to-use-var-and-when-to-use-strongly-types and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125262/should-i-encourage-junior-developers-to-use-explicit-or-implicit-typing and http://resharper.blogspot.com/2008/03/varification-using-implicitly-typed.html and http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/CSharp-var

Comment: So it is only "what i like to see" and it is not imrove performance?