# Difference between Var type and object type in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone briefly explain the difference between following 2 statements and also when should I use one over the other?

For example, I have a Person class and want to instantiate Person class in another class

```
Person person = new Person();

var person = new Person();
```

Comment: They'll produce exactly the same IL code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41479/464709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are compiled to the same MSIL code. The only difference is a possible convenience for you while writing source code - if you decide to change the type of `p` later on, you only have to replace `Person` once in the constructor call and you can leave the variable declaration intact when using `var`.

That said, `var` goes along with a slight decrease in legibility, as you cannot see the type of `p` instantly any more at the beginning of your line. Therefore, restrict your use of `var` to occasions where it really saves some typing, such as for complicated nested generic types.

Note that, if you do *not* initialize your variable right away (in the same statement where the variable is declared), you cannot use `var` as the compiler cannot infer the type of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference, it's just a *syntactic sugar*:

…An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type…

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please reference [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

The first is explicit declaration while the second is implicit(the compiler will decide the object). Otherwise they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

no difference here. `var` is translated in `Person` during the compile time. I usually use `var` to make the refactoring of code faster, I mean that if you decide to change the type of `p`, you can simply change the right side and let `var`.