# Interface: Declaring a class with inherited interface

Tags: c#, oop

I'm not sure what this is call or how to google for an explanation but here goes

let said I have a interface call IView and a class inherited IView call View class. In some projects I see the below code:

```
IView view = new View();
```

Why do that? Why not just do

```
var view = new View();
```

Is there a purpose for declaring a interface then create a View object? why not do the second step?

Comment: This is most likely a dupe, but generally coding like the first is preferred because it is more readable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `var` keyword, the type of the variable will be automatically detected and will probably be of the type `View` instead of `IView`. It's more clear to the reader of your code that you actually meant to have an `IView` reference.

The idea of interfaces, is that it doesn't matter which class implements them, so your code is built upon the knowledge that this .. thing.. implements all IView's properties and methods, disregarding which class it is.

A setup like this will allow you to easily insert different classes later. You could substitute this line for a call to an IView [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) of which you don't know at all which class instance it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You might need view to be something other than whatever View is, for example, if View is a class of SpecialView, then `var view` won't allow you to later assign something that is a GenericView to it even though they both have an IView interface.