# What is the difference between String and string and var?

Tags: string

I have this use case:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

  public class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var test2 = "Name";
      string test1 = "Name";
      String test3 = "Name";

     Console.WriteLine(test1 + test2 + test3 + "NameNotDefined");
   }
 }
}
```

What will do the compiler:

- in this line `Console.WriteLine(test1 + test2 + test3 + "Alugili");`?
- with the last one `"NameNotDefined"`?

Did the compiler call `ToString()` to each of them and than apply the + Operator?

Any body can please explain to me the difference between the var and String and string and "" and how the complier will interact with them?

Comment: Oh god, kill me now..

Comment: `string` is an alias of `System.String`

`var` is temporary varaible

Comment: @user1671639 What the hell are you even talking about ?

Comment: They are all the same (var is changed to string based on semantics by the compiler)

Comment: @user1671639 `var` is not temporary... it's implicitly typed local variable.

Comment: Another topic involved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2866075/14357

Comment: I have a feeling ppl here closing a questions before even read it!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @BassamAlugili Is it too much to ask to read the documentation? Everyone did read your question and closed it appropriately

Comment: Your question is void as you haven't understood how the variables are defined to begin with, you basically have `string + string + string` if it will help you understand

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek `var` keyword is used to refer vary datatype within a local scope, is my understanding.  Please correct me if I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

All three compile identically in C#.  The "var" keyword is used to infer the type at compile-time, and the compiler infers that you're using a string (which is the same thing as String).

Answer (score 1):

`string` is an alias for `System.String`, both of them compile to the same code, so at execution time there is no difference.

The `+` is used for string concatenation, so when you write `test1 + test2 + test3 + "Alugili"` it concatenates all of the strings and form one string. In .net string's are immutable i.e. strings cannot be altered. When you alter a string, you are actually creating a new string.

About var [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) says this :

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two declarations of i are functionally equivalent:

Comment: So in the last one "Alugili" a new object of type string will be created and injected to code you mean that?

Comment: @Bassam Alugili - Yes, for more info check out this MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28v=vs.90%29.aspx