# Limit GridView edit to only one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview set up like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewUsers" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSourceUsers"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" 
            SortExpression="username" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="role" SortExpression="role">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRoles" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="AccessDataSourceRoles" DataTextField="role" DataValueField="role" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("role") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("role") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So the gridview contains a list of users and their roles, upon selecting edit the roles column cells turn into dropdown lists containing roles (currently only Admin and Member).

The issue I'm currently tackling is getting the appropriate values from the gridview (username and selected value from the dropdown list) into the parameters of the update query.

Current codebehind:

```
protected void AccessDataSourceUsers_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridViewUsers.Rows[GridViewUsers.EditIndex];
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownListRoles");

    AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add("@role", ddl.SelectedValue);
    AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add("@username", row.Cells[0].Text);
}
```

I managed to get the selected value of the dropdownlist just fine, however I can't get the username, instead I only get an empty string. I'm assuming that's because upon clicking edit the username field turns into a textbox.

How could I prevent editing the username column so that the cells don't turn into a textbox (I only wish for the roles column to be editable). And also will that automatically fix the problem of getting the value through `row.Cells[0].Text` or is there something else I'm missing here?

**EDIT:** Issue 2. : Parameters and query

My update command looks like this:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE users
 SET users.roleID = DLookup( &quot;[id]&quot; , &quot;roles&quot; , &quot;[role] = '?'&quot;)
WHERE ((username = '?'));
```

Codebehind parameters:

```
protected void GridViewUsers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridViewUsers.Rows[GridViewUsers.EditIndex];
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownListRoles");
    Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("LabelItemEditUsername");

    if (ddl != null && ddl.SelectedValue != null && lbl != null)
    {
        AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add("?", System.Data.DbType.String, ddl.SelectedValue); // I've also tried this without specifying the DbType
        AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add("?", System.Data.DbType.String, lbl.Text);
        int result = AccessDataSourceUsers.Update();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateCommand);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters[0]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters[1]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

After clicking update on gridview the debug values in output are:

```
UPDATE users
 SET users.roleID = DLookup( "[id]" , "roles" , "[role] = '?'")
WHERE ((username = '?'));


?
?
0
```

I'm using `?` due to this line in [Retrieving Data Using the AccessDataSource Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  : `Because the AccessDataSource control extends the SqlDataSource class and uses the System.Data.OleDb provider, you specify parameter placeholders using the "?" placeholder character. The System.Data.OleDb provider does not support named parameters;`

What is weird is that there are two empty lines and then the two placeholder names. Isn't `AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters[0]` supposed to return the value of the parameter, and `AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters[0].Name` return the name? Are the two empty lines supposed to be values? If so why are they empty?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's about replacing the bound field with another template field? Your markup should look like this:
**EDIT 2 :** Regarding your second question---

1. I would check my UpdateCommand for the extra lines. I can't see the
   closed quotation in your command. I have this UpdateCommand
   `UpdateCommand="UPDATE users SET users.roleID =
   DLookup('[id]','roles', '[role]'=?) WHERE username = ?"` and don't
   have any empty line in debug.
2. To see the value, you have to get `DefaultValue` of the parameter
   like :`AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters[0].DefaultValue`.

**EDIT :** I don't think you can set the parameters in AccessDatasource_Updating. **GridView's RowUpdating** is better place to do this.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUsers" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSourceUsers"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowUpdating="GridViewUsers_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="role" SortExpression="role">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRoles" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="AccessDataSourceRoles" DataTextField="role" DataValueField="role" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("role") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("role") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

You can find the label in template field in code:

```
protected void AccessDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
  // Moved code to the method below
}

protected void GridViewUsers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridViewUsers.Rows[GridViewUsers.EditIndex];
    var ddl = row.FindControl("DropDownListRoles") as DropDownList;
    var lblUserName = row.FindControl("lblUserName") as Label;
    if (ddl != null && ddl.SelectedValue != null && lblUserName != null)
    {
        AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add("@role", ddl.SelectedValue);
        AccessDataSourceUsers.UpdateParameters.Add("@username", lblUserName.Text);
        AccessDataSourceUsers.Update();
    }
}
```

I have tested the code above. Hope it helps!

Comment: That did work. Thanks! I actually thought of making the username column a template field and have it contain a label instead of a textbox, though I decided to ask to see if that was the preferred way. Now I just have to figure out why my update command is throwing 0 as a result. Also one question. Is there an advantage to using `var` -> `as` over strong typing -> casting? I know `var` is like `auto` in C++ in that it deduces the type automagically though it's my first time seeing the `as` keyword.

Comment: I have another oddity with the parameters so I'll update the OP and if you got a bit of time to assist me.

Comment: @MrPlow - please see my edit. About `var`, here is a nice discussion:[Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41479/690329).

Comment: Thanks for the update, the issue was that I accidentally added empty parameters in the markup which overwrote the codebehind parameters. The query still doesn't work though so I'm thinking of switching to MySQL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't say Access is a good choice, but in your code it should work. If you want to look at the code that worked for me, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0aEEzcFBXSFNCNzg/edit?usp=sharing) is my test project.

Comment: I tried your project without changing anything and when updating the item updated dissapears. Upon inspecting the db in access the user id gets replaced with an empty or NULL value. It seems like this all could have something to do with some aspect of how something is configured on my PC. I chose Access because I didn't know how much of a pain it would be, and I thought it'd be easier if I didn't have to use xampp to run an SQL server but just have a database file. I migrated to MySQL. Thanks a bunch for taking your time to help me. Really appreciated.

Comment: @MrPlow - maybe it's your PC, or the dll's you have. I can remember in my last job We had to use Access and ran into weird issues :(

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very simple
open the aspx file at design mode and edit the GridView as the following image
[image: Edit the GridView Columns]

Then mark the column that you want to be not editable as read only as following

[image: Read only -->true]