# c++ auto - convenience and confusion

Tags: c++, c++11

I am starting picking up c++11 and at this point I have a love-n-hate of "auto".

No doubt it is convenient.

But it is also confusing, here is a code:

```
auto w = foo->get_w();
auto i = w->get_i();
bar(i);
```

In this code, `get_w()` function returns "struct S*" which is w's type. But struct S has 2 overloaded get_i():

```
const I* get_i() const;
unique_ptr<I>& get_i();
```

Because w is not `const`, so it is the 2nd `get_i()` gets called, and thus `bar(i)` should be `bar(move(i))` because bar() signature is `void bar(unique_ptr<I>)`.

But in reality, it is easy to get track lost.

It is good that this is caught in compile time, but, i guess, my initial enthusiasm is waning.

How do you think? Any tip?

Comment: What is the prototype of `bar`?

Comment: My opinion is that the problem here is with confusing const-overloading. The two types are completely unrelated. You may want to talk with the author of the struct `S`.

Comment: Seems rather odd that you would overload a function with completely different signatures.

Comment: I think your question may be too subjective for this site, as it asks for opinions ("What do you think?").

Comment: I think it's primarily opinion based. Some find `auto` amazing, other hate it, and there are all the nuances in between. Pick your nuance :) I do agree that sometimes it gets confusing, but on the other hand, I use auto most of the time for my iterators. A rule of thumb I keep is that it should not be confusing. Then, the definitions of "confusing" may vary...

Comment: Also, `auto i = w->get_i();` won't compile if `get_i()` is returning a `unique_ptr<I>&`.

Comment: The problem with your code isn't the use of `auto` but the terrible choice of names like `foo`, `get_w`, `get_i` and `bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this question, I have to link this excellent article by Herb Sutter: [GotW #94 Solution: AAA Style (Almost Always Auto)](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

You can read his opinion already from the title. He also brings up this guideline the rationale of which is explained in the article:

> Guideline: Remember that preferring `auto` variables is motivated primarily by correctness, performance, maintainability, and robustness—and only lastly about typing convenience.

The main aspects about `auto` that he praises is that it avoids unwanted implicit conversions, of which there are plenty in C++ and that it makes callers less dependent on functions interfaces, since a change in return type is automatically reflected in the local variables' type. `auto` is also very useful in template code, since you don't have to access e.g. `Container::value_type`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Whenever it's more convenient than confusing, then use it, else don't.
For a long list of arguments and opinions I'll refer to another, different question: [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)