# when use type inference? we can always use VAR?

Tags: c#

The type inference VAR,serves only to be recognized by the program only if he has to go to replace "int "string" etc.? If yes,would it not be better to always use VAR?

Comment: Not even sure what you mean, use type inference when you want easy refactoring. Still need concrete types for casting

Comment: No, personally I prefer to explicity write int or string or whatever because it is clearer. But var is fine if your variables are named well or it's obvious what you're doing.

Comment: You cannot always use var, at least for expressions like var myVar = null;

Comment: Using it explicitly makes refactoring so difficult!

Comment: var keyword makes refactoring easier - if you wanted to change return types of methods, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can always use var except in two instances: when you want to initialize a variable to null and when you're assigning a Delegate to a variable. I always use var whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pros and cons to using the var keyword.

**What are the benefits of using var**

- Dont Repeat Yourself (DRY) – Redundant code should be avoided.
- Faster creation of code
- Calls for improved naming of variables – can work as a reminder for descriptive naming
- Improved readability – in some cases (where the repeated type is long and complex)
- Less code modification if you later need to change the type
- Clearer distinction of when you really want to specify the type

**The disadvantages of using var**

- Loss of readability – in some cases (where the type isn’t obvious)
- Changes to the type could introduce bugs which the compiler otherwise would have caught for the developer

**+ Good:**

- `var numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};`
- `var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();`
- `var cars = new List();`
- `var orders = new Dictionary();`

**+/- OK with either (but prefer explicit declaration):**

- `int pages = 10;`
- `string username = “john”;`
- `var username = “john”;`
- `var order = GetOrder(orderId); // ok if the type is Order, otherwise not`
- `for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++)`

**- Bad:**

- `var settings = GetInboxSettings(); // not obvious at all`
- `var userId = GetUserId(); // ambigous, is this guid, string, int or a custom UserId object?`
- `Dictionary orders = new Dictionary(); // redundant`

Answer (score 3):

In MSDN, [there are some guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx). Usually, it helps readability in this cases:

1. Declaring a variable with a primitive value: `var i = 0`
2. Declaring an object with a constructor: `var logText = new StringBuilder()`
3. Inside `for` and `foreach` statements: `foreach (var word in dictionary)`
4. Dealing with LINQ queries.

Also, note that [there's a case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) where `var` is obligatory, in the construction of anonymous types.

Comment: +1 for mentioning anonymous types, which was probably the main reason var was introduced.

Comment: Does this answer the original question?

Comment: @DennisTraub the first question in the question is "when [to] use type inference."  This answer answers that question.

Comment: @DennisTraub its kinda hard to decipher what the original question is. To me, looks like OP wanted to know when to use `var`, and I answered it properly.

Comment: @Mephy I'd interpret it differently. OP seems to be asking if there is any reason to *not* use `var`

Answer (score 2):

I usually opt for `var` and try to choose speaking variable names. But in some cases using the actual type can be very helpful:

- In some special cases it might make the code more readable to use the actual type.
- You might want to initialize a variable with `null` (which is an arguable practice), wich prevents the compiler from infering the type.
- Quite often, especially when coding against interfaces and abstractions, you want to explicitly use an interface or a base type as in `IEnumerable<Item> items = new List<Item>()`

Comment: what about refactoring though....

Comment: Can you give a real example when "you want to explicitly use an interface or a basetype as in IEnumerable<Item> items = new List<Item>()"?

Comment: I think his point is that you can't *always* use var... which is what the question is asking. Not "are there positive aspects to using var?"

Comment: @No1_Melman sometimes its actually nice, because it will cause a compile time error and you can make sure the change didn't break anything else. Leave it there and you could have some sneaky errors show up afterwards because *you really needed* that variable to be a float, and not a double.

Comment: @ValentinP. sure: `IEnumerable<Item> items = new List<Item>(); if (something) items = items.Where(i => i.Value > threshold);`

Comment: @No1_Melman Automatic refactoring won't be a problem with explicit types, given you use the proper tools.

Comment: @phoog, ok, you are right :) I remember another one case. It is usefull for Explicit Interface Method Invocation

Comment: @ValentinP. Basically because you should try to follow two of the most basic principles of object-oriented programming: *1. Code against abstractions instead of concrete implementations* and *2. Favor composition over inheritance*. Both of which can be found in the OO-classic *Design Patterns* by Gamma et al.

Comment: @ValentinP. this is for calling an extension method that is defined on `IEnumerable<T>` and returns `IEnumerable<T>`.  The variable `items` therefore can't have the type `List<T>`.  Another solution would be to use a second variable, but I've used this technique quite a bit and I find it is very useful to avoid declaring the second variable.

Comment: @DennisTraub, declaring of local variable has nothing impact on SOLID, GoF, OOP, etc. That's why I asked.

Comment: @ValentinP. Of course it does.

Comment: @DennisTraub, there were presented at least two cases - EIMI by me and "one variable optimization" by phoog. Both are mostly of "technical" nature. It would be great if you provide a GoF pattern where explicit (!) local variable cast makes sense.

Comment: I'm not speaking of patterns, I'm speaking of principles. (The first part of the book, the one without pictures). And I'm not talking about explicit local variable casting either.

Comment: @DennisTraub, ok, but we discuss here certain case - using of var keyword, which is applicable only for local variable declaration. Using of explicit classes instead of var is equally to "safe explicit" cast. I am not talking about class fields or method arguments. There are no principles applicable to this certain case. Blind adherence to "some principles" always ends up in overkill. It is all about what you are writing now. I think that talking about principles you should understand the reasons why it was developed: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Principles_and_Patterns.pdf