# using var instead of specific type

Tags: c#, function, variables, return, definition

I'm working on an ASP .NET MVC application, and i'm the inexperienced guy on a team of 3. 
One of my colleagues, the most experienced guy on the team, is constantly using var when defining a variable, although the functions that he uses to load the variable return a specific type(int, string and so on), is this a good practice?

I confronted him with this question but the answer he gave me was "i don't know search for it...", the experienced guy answer, you know...

So, is this a good practice?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is [well covered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Agreed, so closing. It's a matter of opinion anyway. Personally, I used to dislike it in most cases, but grew to like it.

Comment: The question linked, is quite different, this question is questioning if it's good practise.

Comment: This is addressed by by the [Microsoft C# Coding Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) - see the section on *Implicitly Typed Local Variables*.

Comment: @jamierocks That's exactly what that other question asks too: not when it's valid, but when it's appropriate.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. For example, if right side of expression returns a complex type like a list or an object i use `var` and if a primitive value is returned then i use explicitly define variable type