# Shortcut for extract local variable in Visual Studio or ReSharper (for C#)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for extracting local variable in VS or ReSharper? I know that there are shortcut for extracting field variable but I cannot find for extracting local variable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-clicking a local variable, I get this context menu:

[image: ReSharper Context Menu]

Assuming you want shortcuts for the highlighted commands, you can define your own shortcuts through the Visual Studio keyboard mapper. (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard)

- Introduce Variable... = "ReSharper.ReSharper_IntroVariable"
- Introduce Field... = "ReSharper.ReSharper_IntroduceField"
- Introduce Parameter... = "ReSharper.ReSharper_IntroParameter"

FYI My keyboard shortcuts were set by ReSharper via ReSharper -> Options -> Keyboard & Menus and applying the "Visual Studio" scheme.

(Using Visual Studio Community 2015 and ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way when extracting variable to be exact type? For example to be `double x`, not always `var x` ? Or this is a better practice(to use `var` instead of concrete types) in C#?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @DPM I don't think so. ReSharper pushes the `var` keyword pretty hard. As for the usage, I'll refer you to this: [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41479/1433521).