# How to automatically add variable type from method return type in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Suppose you have a class and method:

```
public class MyLogicClass
{
    public static MyCustomComplexType GetResult() => new MyCustomComplexType ();
}
```

And while writing code you'd write:

```
MyLogicClass.GetResult();
```

Is there any shortcut or other way to automatically add the return type of the method as a variable, possibly with variable name, so the result woudl be for example:

```
MyCustomComplexType myCustomComplexType1 = MyLogicClass.GetResult();
```

Comment: No there isn't. But since that is a method you could theroretically call it without even assigning the returned value to a variable, so your current code is absolutely valid. How should visual studio decide to prepend it with a variable declaration if it's not even clear that you want it?

Comment: *var* isn't good enough anymore?

Comment: You could use var and let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: @user6144226: well, `var` doesn't say anything about the variable type, so no, its not good enough if the type is not obvious (like in this case).

Comment: If you have JetBrains ReSharper installed, that will do it for you. Of course, that's not native to Visual Studio, so it's not necessarily what you're looking for.

Comment: And if you somehow don't have Resharper - maybe this VS refactoring will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/introduce-local-variable

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I would like to press a shortcut key if wanted  visual studio to add the code. I understand this can't be added automatically without user interaction...

Comment: @Evk: i have vs 2017 but quick actions and refactoring only provides "extract method" if i select `MyLogicClass.GetResult()`

Comment: @Evk 'introduce local' only seems to work if there's already a variable name defined, oddly enough...

Comment: You can use `var x = MyLogicClass.GetResult();` and then use a refactoring shortcut to make `var` explicit. That's what I do in many cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, this would be enough for me, but I can't find the refactoring option in VS to make var explicit? How do you do that? I tried the VS2017 answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289743/tool-to-refactor-c-sharp-var-to-explicit-type , but this doesn' seem to work? It just says 'Extract method'.

Comment: @RunCMD: I have CodeRush for Roslyn installed, and it may be that that's giving the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of JonSkeet above, and the 'Visaul Studio answer' of this question: [Tool to refactor C# var to explicit type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289743/tool-to-refactor-c-sharp-var-to-explicit-type) , I managed to get this working in Visual Studio:

- Find Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General > 'var' 
  preferences

  Set the 'severity' of the desired options to 'Warning'
- After typing

  ```
  var x = MyLogicClass.GetResult();
  ```

  just press 'CTRL + **.**' and choose 'Use explicit type instead of var' (or hit ENTER)

  this will change the code to:

  ```
  MyCustomComplexType x = MyLogicClass.GetResult();
  ```

Answer (score -2):

First of you would implement the method in the class in this way, and use the object return type

```
public class MyLogicClass
{
  public static object GetResult()
  {
    //Method code goes here
  }
}
```

And implement it as:

```
MyLogicClass mlc = new MyLogicClass();
MyLogicClass.GetResult();
```

**EDIT:** I didn't understan you properly the first time try this: [Shortcut for extract local variable in Visual Studio or ReSharper (for C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850527/shortcut-for-extract-local-variable-in-visual-studio-or-resharper-for-c)

Comment: It seems you havent understood OP's requirement. He wonders if there is a way(shortcut) to introduce the local variable declaration automatically

Comment: The link you supplied only works for Resharper I'm afraid