# Use Variable In SQL String

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I add a variable to my SQL string and run it against the server successfully?  I want to run this statement through my C#

```
protected void RunSQLQuery(string salesman, string connectionString)
{
    SqlConnection cnn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.Append("update database ");
    sql.Append("set shippdate = GetDate() ");
    sql.Append("where salesman = "' + salesman + "'");
    sql.Append("and managerapproval is not null ");
    cnn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), cnn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    cnn.Close
}
```

This presents multiple compile errors underlining my +salesman+ code.  The errors are:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement
>
> ; expected
>
> ) expected
>
> Too many characters in character literal Newline in constant

Comment: Where are people learning this crap.

Comment: #1 - this is bad. Concatenation will open you up to SQL injection attacks. Look up SQL parameterization. #2 - your quotes are in the wrong order: `salesman = "' + salesman` should be `salesman = '" + salesman`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are *not* adding the string object that `salesman` refers, you are adding `salesman` as a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal).

Just add it as a parameter like;

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("update database set shippdate = GetDate() where salesman = @salesman");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesman", salesman);
...
```

And use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) to execute your command, not `SqlDataReader`. This `SqlDataReader` is for return some data.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

As a full example;

```
protected void RunSQLQuery(string salesman, string connectionString)
{
    using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
         cmd.CommandText = @"update database set shippdate = GetDate() 
                             where salesman = @salesman";
         // I assume your column is nvarchar
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesman", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = salesman;
         cnn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

For myself, I always prefer to use [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify my parameter type and it's size but since you *never* mentioned your `salesman` column type, I couldn't post this in my example.

Comment: looks like you have a typo after `GetDate()` in your query.

Comment: @SonerGönül - I thought using var variable types was bad practice?  Am I mis-informed on that?

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy you have been misinformed. Var in C# is not bad, the type is inferred from the right hand side. So no its not bad.

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy I use `var`  all the time, personally. You can read [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41479/447156) as well for more perspectives.

Comment: The [Add overload you are calling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx) in your examples is marked as Obsolete in the MSDN.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's the another reason why I like `Add(string, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload :) Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can also see from the syntax highlighting, the compile errors are caused because you did not escape the quotes properly in `sql.Append("where salesman = "' + salesman + "'");`.

As a side note, you should never insert strings into sql queries without first validating them, or you are open to sql injection, e.g. if i pass  `"''; drop table database;"` as salesman parameter. It is better to use `SqlParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above answers, yes, writing queries in this way is not a good way to do it. But still if you want to do it that way only, you will have to change:

```
sql.Append("where salesman = "' + salesman + "'");
```

to

```
sql.Append("where salesman = '" + salesman + "'");
```

Comment: Stop teaching people bad habits. You say "You should not be doing it this way" but you still only show the bad way to do it, why? Please explain your reasoning for encouraging people to write dangerous code that can cause security compromises in their system.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `AddWithValue` method from your sql command combined with the `UPPER` function to make it case insensitive:

```
SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE database SET shippdate = GetDate() WHERE UPPER(salesman) = UPPER(@salesMan)";   
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesMan", salesman);
if (cnn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
{
      cnn.Open();
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: This doesn't really directly answer the question. SQL is typically case-insensitive anyways.