# Declaring variables using 'var' keyword

Tags: c#

I hardly ever use the var variable type declaration in my C# code.  Usually only when doing an odd HTML to ASP cast so, very rare.

But some programmers seem to always use var.  Why would you do this?

C# is a strongly typed language.  I would think that would make it bad-form to use a var declaration most of the time.

Comment: I dont think you know what `var` is

Comment: `var` is not equal to `dynamic`, it is an "implicitly typed field", so this is still *strongly typed*

Comment: Say I have a method that turns MyBlueClass, and I assign that returned value to a variable. I can either use var, or MyBlueClass. In the future, for whatever reason, I change that same method to return MyRedClass. If I used var originally, there's now a lot less work that needs to be done.

Comment: You really need to read an introduction to the `var` keyword

Comment: `var` is just short-hand for "let the compiler figure out the variable type from what is on the right". It is not dynamic or runtime determined.

Comment: To assist you on your learning journey, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `var i = 1` - OK. `var i = myObject.Getsomething()` - not super ok because hard to read, what is `i` going to be? This should be your general guidance. And remember that real reason for `var` is anonymous types/Linq

Comment: @T.S. - even that can draw differing opinions - is it more important *what the specific type of i is* or *that i is whatever you obtain from GetSomething*? Sometimes you care about specific types, sometimes you care more about the algorithms and so long as the code still compiles, you don't care if GetSomething changes from returning an int to returning a long.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know what you're saying and I am familiar with this discussion. This is gray area. But man, how helpful `int i = myObject.Getsomething()` during code reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, `var`is still strongly typed, it is not the same as `dynamic`. The difference is that it is calculated implicitly instead of explicitly declaring it.

As most C# developers use Visual Studio, you can check the real type by hovering your mouse over the variable in case you need it.

The use of var is extended due to simplifying developing, as many times it is either obvious or too complex (several generic types, etc.)

Comment: Best answer I have seen.

Comment: *"As most C# developers use Visual Studio, you can check the real type by hovering your mouse over the variable in case you need it."* And then all hell breaks out, when you do code reviews, either in TFS web-based tools or even in the studio comparison tools when hovering is not always produces the hint.

Comment: @TheJoe If you like this answer, why don't you just accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the var keyword in c# is to shorten variable declaration. it's there for ease of use.

For example:

```
var myObj = new SuperLongClassNameHere();
```

because of the right hand side, you already know its type, it saves you from having to type out potentially long names twice.

var does not create a variant type, the type is simply inferred by the compiler. If it cannot be inferred, it will generate a compiler error

Comment: no. This is not main reason. that would be **anonymous types**.

Comment: Anonymous types shorten initialization.  `var` is part of the declaration.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey `var` can be used only with initialization, never declaration-only. And Anonymous types are there for not pre-declaring one every time and LINQ of course.