# should i use var or toArray() to convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> to string[]

Tags: c#

which one is the best way of doing the following and why?

```
string[] doubleArray = Regex
  .Split(strValue, @"[^0-9\.]+")
  .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "")
  .ToArray();  // here i have used toarray 

var doubleArray = Regex
  .Split(strValue, @"[^0-9\.]+")
  .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != ""); // and here i have used var
```

.

Comment: The keyword `var` is only syntactic sugar, compiler uses the data type (in your example `string[]`), personally I do only use it only when VeryLongClassNamesAreUsed to make it more readable.

Comment: Very related, probably duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion between `string[]` and `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you want a string array you should either.

```
var doubleArray = Regex.Split(strValue, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "").ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] doubleArray = Regex.Split(strValue, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "").ToArray();
```

Do note in both cases the `.ToArray()` is used to enumerate the `IEnumerable` and get an array out of it.

In both cases the underlying type is `string[]` because the `var` keyword [is only syntactic sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

Comment: @user3129097 Check my latest edit, where I add link to `var` keyword documentation, it does fully explain you your question. If you think my answer is helpful, [accept it as useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: "personally I do only use it only when VeryLongClassNamesAreUsed to make it more readable" could u please give me one example

Comment: and i noticed one more thing the second one when iterates it goes back to the .where() "Regex.Split(strValue, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");"

foreach (var item in doubleArray.AsQueryable())
{

Console.WriteLine(doubleArray[i]);

}


i think it needs  tolist(), please suggest what should be used?