# How do you pass a dictionary into a class C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

**The problem: How do I pass the Dictionary from Search.Part2 into Search.Main**

main part is

```
namespace Search
{
     public class Search1 : Search
     {
         public static void Search1(string[] input)
         {  
             string[] array = Search.part1(input);
             var dictionary = Search.part2(input);
             Search.Main(input, array, dictionary);
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
    }
}
```

problem is

```
public static void Main(string[] input, string[] array, 'var' dictionary)
```

I cant use the contextual keyword 'var' as it may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code. this maybe simple but idk what to put instead of var (or if i can even do it this way)

Comment: See [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Use the actual type instead of `var`, then. `var` is just syntactical sugar over the actual type. It appears that it would be the same type that `Search.part2` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

`void MyMethod(Dictionary<string,string> dictionary)`

For you case

`Dictionary<string, string>` will be whatever the type `Search.part2(input)` returns.

---

#### Documentation

Please see [C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables), specifically [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables#remarks). Here is just one sentence, from it:

> Implicit typing with the var keyword can only be applied to variables at local method scope.

See also [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)